# Is there a way to change the locale/language on an iOS Simulator through code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

I was searching for a way to change the iOS device Locale without having to go through the settings and importing some new framework. Just a simple script or so would be great, or even a piece of code. I was wondering if there was something like :

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] setLocale:@"WhateverLocale"];
```

Comment: You cannot change the language of the device.  but you can make YOUR application default to a particular language.  Why do you want to change the language of the device programmatically?

Comment: Because I wanted to see how two labels behave when I used Localized Strings.

Comment: The answer I gave you is sufficient for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not fulfill your needs, but one way to gain programmatic access over the app's current locale is to override the `AppleLanguages` key in NSUserDefaults. For example, to change to French:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[ @"fr" ]
                                          forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The downside to this approach is that you need to close and reopen the app for the change to take effect.

Note, to return to the system default, simply call:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```